# My data from database isn't displayed in jQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I want to display the data from database in [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) but it doesn't display the data. It just show the a simple list that I posted below I try too many things I found some related question but they are in PHP which I didn't understand as I don't know any thing about PHP.

**Jquery ajax** :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#demoGrid").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "info": true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Login/Display",
            "type": "GET"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "EmployeeId", "orderable": true },
            { "data": "Name", "orderable": true },
            { "data": "Position", "orderable": true },
            { "data": "Office", "orderable": true },
            { "data": "Salary", "orderable": true },
        ],
        "order": [[0, "asc"]]
    });
});
```

**Controller** :

```
public ActionResult Display()
        {
            List<Empdetail> list = new List<Empdetail>();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Connection.connection con = new Connection.connection();
            ds = con.mydata();
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                list.Add(new Empdetail
                {
                    EmployeeId = (int)(dr["EmployeeId"]),
                    Name = (string)dr["Name"],
                    Position = (string)dr["Position"],
                    Office = (string)(dr["Office"]),
                    Salary = (int)(dr["Salary"]),
                });
            }
            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Model :**

```
public class Empdetail
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Office { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output** :

```
[{"EmployeeId":1,"Name":"Imran Khan","Position":"PM","Office":"PM House","Salary":1000000}]
```

Comment: Use `ajax:{dataSrc:''....` since your data source array is not encompassed into object property.

Comment: I use it but it also didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to return data in specific format for `Datatable` from Controller, as:

```
    return Json(new
    {
        draw = "1",
        recordsTotal = list.count,
        recordsFiltered = list.count,
        data = List
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

for more reference check [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data).

Comment: After Adding this return Json(new
            {
                draw = "1",
                recordsTotal = list.Count,
                list.Count,
                data = list
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); i got thsi output  {"draw":"1","recordsTotal":1,"Count":1,"data":[{"EmployeeId":1,"Name":"Imran Khan","Position":"PM","Office":"PM House","Salary":1000000}]}

Comment: I was missing one parameter `recordsFiltered` in above. I have updated my answer. Please check and let me know if you still not getting data in Datatable.

Comment: I still getting the above output

Comment: Are you getting data in Datatable? if not, please check the browser console for any error. It might help.

Comment: I am not getting data in the datatable and i check the browser console it didn't show any error